# Qt - How to append to a local list from a const function

Tags: c++, qt, list, constants

I am working in Qt 4.7. I have a class that is a subclass from QAbstractTableModel. I need to have a local QList, called intlist, to keep track of any columns where the header is a specific value. These headers are stored in a QStringList called headerNames. Right now I have this:

```
QVariant myTableClass::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if(headerNames[index.column()] == "TriggerText")
  {
    this->intlist.append(index.column();
  }
  return QVariant;
}
```

When I try to build this, it gives me the error "C2663: 'QList::append': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer". I tried it several different ways based on tips given to similar problems I found online, including: using just intlist instead of this->intlist; setting an int to the value of index.column() then using that int in the append instead; and creating a separate non-const function to call that appends the value. They all give the same error. I'm completely lost as to what to do. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Declare the `intlist` member `mutable`, and you should be able to modify it from within a `const` function.

Comment: Note that your code tracks any *access* to triggering columns. Is this what you want to do? Also `return` statement is invalid, please include valid code to avoid confusing the real issue.

Comment: note that you are subclassing a method from the Qt API, to completely deviate from what the method is supposd to do. I will not be surprised if your code misbehave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to modify a member from within a `const` member function, you can add `mutable` to the declaration of that member you want to modify.

The member should probably be private, and the state of that member shouldn't affect the public state that is exposed to the users of your class, who are expecting your member function to have no effect on the object.

See [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk.aspx), or perhaps section 16.2.9.3 from `The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition` by Bjarne Stroustrup. `mutable` was available prior to C++11.

Comment: mutable seems better than using const_cast +1

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers miss the real issue: *There is absolutely no sense in tracking changes in a const accessor method*. It wouldn't make sense even if it was a proxy model.

You should update intlist wherever your header names are changed. For example, assuming that `m_headerNames` reflects the header names visible to the outside of the model:

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
  QList<int> m_intlist;
  QList<QString> m_headerNames;
  Q_SLOT void trackHeaderData() {
    m_intList.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_headerNames.size(); ++i) {
      if (m_headerNames[i] == QStringLiteral("TriggerText"))
        m_intList << i;
    }
  }
public:
  MyModel( ... ) {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(headerDataChanged(Qt::Orientation,int,int)),
                  SLOT(trackHeaderData()));
  }
};
```

Of course this won't work if you don't properly emit the `headerDataChanged` signal; if you don't, then your model is broken.

Comment: Not sure what original intention is, but question *code* does not track changes, it tracks accesses.

Comment: @hyde It tracks changes to `headerNames`, but does so in a const accessor method. Those `headerNames` are changed elsewhere, and that's where the tracking code belongs, or at least as I've shown in a slot that's connected to a notification signal.